# Output file from Point Sampling Tool plugin returns data but no sample ID using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, point

I have sampling points in QGIS which all have a unique ID, and I'm trying to collect various geographic and climate data for those points from a variety of sources. Although the source raster data varies depending on what I'm measuring, I'm always using the Point Sampling Tool plugin to collect the data. The data are correct, but there is never an ID column in the output.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Use `join attributes by location` to add the ID from the original layer to the new layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a points vector layer, and two raster layers (one is an averaged resample of the other one).
The points layer has three attributes, *fid* is a unique identifier, *class* is a numeric classification and *old_or_new* is a text string classification.

If I want the points with *fid* and *class* attributes, and both rasters band1 pixel values sampled, I need to select all that combinations of layer/attribute in the _General tab of the plugin:

[image: 1]

---

In the *Fields* tab, there are the fields will be extracted to the output points:

[image: 2]

---

If you select the fields of the source points layer, then the *sampled_points* layer must have those attributes for each feature:

[image: 3]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Worked perfectly!